# How to get recent changesets in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I remember seeing some interesting code in one of commits but I dont remember which one is it. Is there a way to get last lets say 100 changesets so I can grep through them. Maybe my terminology is bad so Ill explain with words. 
Im looking for 
diffs ala

+cout << "hello";
-cout << "Hello";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you literally asked for is as simple as `hg log --patch --limit 100` which gets all revisions, but I upvoted @sherlock's answer using `hg grep` because that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to search a piece of code in the history, `hg grep` will help.

If you want to know which commit introduce this change, use `hg annotate` instead.